# How to verify that a request came from a script on your site?

Tags: javascript, facebook, security, facebook-login

I'm currently implementing the Javascript Facebook login API.

Based on the callback response from Facebook, this client side script then sends a request with query string parameters to a URL on our site. Based on the email in that URL, the client is authenticated.

This is not secure. No other token that we can verify against is returned from Facebook (as far as I know), and we are expected to log the user in based on an email in a query string parameter, and no password.

I'd like to add another query string parameter that gives us some sort of assurance that the query string data came from a JavaScript redirect following the response from Facebook.

I'm thinking that this should be some sort of hashed value created by a client script that I can compare against server side. However, every resource used to create this secret key would be available to an attacker, via client cookies or through inspecting the client script.

Is there a common and secure approach to this problem that I can use?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook apparently uses [OAuth](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login). Without getting into too much details (which you could find in relevant OAuth and FB documentation), OAuth operates with a secret shared between your *server* and the service provider (Facebook, in this instance), which is never revealed to the frontend Javascript, and is used to confirm if the callback you receive is genuine.

Answer (score 0):

Pass Facebook a unique callback URL each time you authenticate user.

This URL should contain some security token, which, if present, will identify the authenticity of the logon attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `state` variable to your requests to Facebook. This will be returned to you by Facebook to validate your request.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/